# How to playback audio (.WAV file) by using openal.world file?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The openal.world file includes `<audio_source>` and `<audio_sink>` for two models respectively. the collision could trigger audio playback. the original file is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<sdf version="1.5">
  <world name="default">
    <include>
      <uri>model://ground_plane</uri>
    </include>
    <include>
      <uri>model://sun</uri>
    </include>
    <audio>
      <device>default</device>
    </audio>
    <model name="box">
      <pose>0 0 10.5 0 0 0</pose>
      <link name="link">
        <collision name="collision">
          <geometry>
            <box>
              <size>1 1 1</size>
            </box>
          </geometry>
        </collision>
        <visual name="visual">
          <geometry>
            <box>
              <size>1 1 1</size>
            </box>
          </geometry>
          <material>
            <script>Gazebo/WoodPallet</script>
          </material>
        </visual>
        <audio_source>
          <uri>file://media/audio/cheer.mp3</uri>
          <pitch>2.0</pitch>
          <gain>1.0</gain>
          <loop>false</loop>
          <contact>
            <collision>collision</collision>
          </contact>
        </audio_source>
      </link>
    </model>
    <model name="sphere">
      <pose>0 1.5 0.5 0 0 0</pose>
      <link name="link">
        <audio_sink />
        <collision name="collision">
          <geometry>
            <sphere>
              <radius>0.5</radius>
            </sphere>
          </geometry>
        </collision>
        <visual name="visual">
          <geometry>
            <sphere>
              <radius>0.5</radius>
            </sphere>
          </geometry>
          <material>
            <script>Gazebo/WoodPallet</script>
          </material>
        </visual>
      </link>
    </model>
  </world>
</sdf>
```

I don't know why I can't hear any sound after one object collide with another object, and I have tried to move the object around the plane, but it still has no sound. PS: the headset is no problem.

It would be grateful if someone can tell me how to play audio files in Gazebo by using OpenAL.

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/16895/how-to-playback-audio-(.wav-file)-by-using-openal.world-file?/) by [Daniel.T](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3664/daniel.t/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-08-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

OpenAL only works if you build Gazebo from source and have the required dependencies installed. See [this](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issues/1984/no-sounds-i-heard-when-i-tried-openalworld).

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2017-08-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Daniel.T](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3664/daniel.t/) on 2017-08-03**:
Gazebo8, Ubuntu 16.04.
When I am building Gazebo8 from source.
[ 17%] Linking CXX shared library libgazebo_common.so
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libavcodec.a(allcodecs.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `ff_h263_vaapi_hwaccel' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/local/lib/libavcodec.a: error adding symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
gazebo/common/CMakeFiles/gazebo_common.dir/build.make:1260: recipe for target 'gazebo/common/libgazeb

**Comment by [Daniel.T](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3664/daniel.t/) on 2017-08-03**:
(follow above comment). Hello Chapulina, thank you very much. I followed that procedure, but I couldn't install gazebo8 from source successful. I guess I should use Gazebo7 with Ubuntu 14.04, and I am still trying. Do you have any idea?

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2017-08-03**:
Have you installed these: libswscale-dev libavutil-dev libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev

**Comment by [Daniel.T](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3664/daniel.t/) on 2017-08-04**:
Yes, I have installed these packages, and just tried it again, it's still unsuccessful. The error reports:

[ 23%] Building CXX object deps/opende/CMakeFiles/gazebo_ode.dir/src/joints/slider.cpp.o
[ 23%] Building CXX object deps/opende/CMakeFiles/gazebo_ode.dir/src/joints/universal.cpp.o
[ 23%] Linking CXX shared library libgazebo_ode.so
[ 23%] Built target gazebo_ode
Makefile:160: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2

Should I use Gazebo7 with Ubuntu 14.04?

**Comment by [Daniel.T](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3664/daniel.t/) on 2017-08-04**:
Thank you very much! I solved the problem. Under Ubuntu 14.04, build Gazebo7 from source according to Chapulina's suggestion, and follow that procedure, you will hear the sounds after you launched openal.world. However, it is still unsuccessful when I build Gazebo8 from source under Ubuntu 16.04.I hope someone could fix this later. So far, my suggestion is to use Gazebo7 with Ubuntu 14.04.